# Kendo grid custom editor how to send the element?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, element

Okay i have this kendogrid

```
$("#configGrid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            {
                title: "Index",
                template: '<span>#: Index #</span>'
            },
            {
                title: "Trigger Bet",
                field: "TriggerBet",
                editor: customEditor(e, 0.01, 2, 0 )
            },
            {
                title: "Rounds Probability",
                field: "RoundsProbability",
                editor: customEditor(e, 10, 0, 0)
            },
            {
                title: "Hot Odds",
                field: "HotOdds",
                editor: customEditor(e, 10, 0, 0)
            },
            {
                title: "Seed amount",
                field: "SeedAmount",
                editor: customEditor(e, 10, 0, 0)
            },
            {
                title: "Contribution",
                field: "Contribution",
                editor: customEditor(e, 0.01, 2, 0)
            }
        ],
        dataSource: {
            data: getConfigDataFromModel().configs,
        },

        editable: true,
        navigatable: true
    });
```

And as you see almost of my columns got this `customEditor` where i want to send with the element itself to this function

```
function customEditor(e, steps, decimals, min) {

    if (e.container.find("[name]").first().attr("name") == "HotOdds") {
        console.log(e.model.JackpotType + "hello");
        if (e.model.JackpotType === "Progressive jackpot") {
            e.sender.closeCell();
        }
    }
    GJP.createEditor(steps, decimals, min);

}
```

The problem is that it is undefined here as what I send from my column doesn't actually send the element. Does anyone know how to properly send the element to my `customEditor` function so it can handle it as intended? Been looking around kendo documentation but I can't seem to find any solution that send the element as a parameter to the custom editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

customEditor(e, 0.01, 2, 0 ) is a function *call* not a function reference which means it executes the function *right now*, as in during the init of the grid where "e" does not exist yet(javascript error), it does not exist until the edit event occurs when you click on the cell and kendo calls the function, providing the "e".

You need to make your editor config a function reference, not an immediate execution.  And since you also want to tack on your own parameters to the "e" that kendo provides, you will need a closure.

So,

Define your editor config as

```
...
editor: function (e) {
    return customEditor(e, 0.01, 2, 0);
}
```

Example:http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/OcIxEGud